# simulate Ctrl+V in electron app

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am working on an electron app and I have a globalShortcut.register event.
What i want is, when user press this shortcut, hide my app window and simulate a paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in the background app like a text editor. This can be made with electron?

Comment: Your app can't do anything outside itself. And anything you would do will have to be platform specific. Electron is a sandbox.

Comment: are you talk about copying text to the clipboard?

Comment: No. copy from clipboard to other apps. simulate Ctrl+V

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use the clipboard, to copy something from your Electron app, use the following code. This makes use of the [clipBoard](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/clipboard/) method:

```
const clipboard = require('electron').clipboard

const copyBtn = document.getElementById('copy-to')
const copyInput = document.getElementById('copy-to-input')

copyBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (copyInput.value !== '') copyInput.value = ''
  copyInput.placeholder = 'Copied! Paste here to see.'
  clipboard.writeText('Electron Demo!')
})
```

If you are looking to do *something* when a certain key combo is hit (like Ctrl+V) you can use an [accelerator](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/accelerator/) or create your own combinations with [globalShortcut](https://electron.atom.io/docs/api/global-shortcut/).

```
const {app, globalShortcut} = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {
  // Register a 'CommandOrControl+Y' shortcut listener.
  globalShortcut.register('CommandOrControl+Y', () => {
    // Do stuff when Y and either Command/Control is pressed.
  })
})
```